Best Practices for Retaining and Managing Subscription-Based Third-Party Extensions After Subscription Cancellation
We have a third-party extension for our Magento store that we purchased on a subscription basis. We've decided not to continue with the subscription, so we cancelled it. However, we want to continue using the current version of the extension on our site.
Our concern is about future Magento upgrades. If a newer version of Magento is released, the extension may have updates that we won't be able to access due to the cancelled subscription. This might cause issues during the upgrade process.
My question is: What is the best way to retain the older version of the extension on our site while ensuring it remains functional and compatible with future Magento upgrades?
Specifically:

Should we move the extension code to app/code and remove it from the Composer-based package?
Are there any potential pitfalls or considerations we should know when taking this approach?
Are there better alternatives to manage this situation?

Any advice or best practices from those who have faced similar scenarios would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

First thing, third party module should never be outside of vendor unless they don't have composer access to get them. This is mostly due to the fact we want to be able to update it easily but not only, it's also to improve all your code analysis process; for example, it doesn't make sense to check modules from vendor with tools like sonar or doing some code coverage.  You want in app/code only your own code.
Then you have to consider a few things, cancelling the subscription is cancelling you the access to the full module or only to the next versions of the module ?
If it cancels the access to the full module then that means you won't be able to retrieve it from composer and you won't be able to use it anymore; unless as you said you take back the code module and paste it into your own app code system...but probably that would be illegal in that case ?
If you still can access old module versions then just keep getting it from composer, you can lock the version so as it's not updated anymore and don't throw you any error like access denied in the future.
Sadly there is no miracle run, if you decide to cancel your module subscription, the day you update magento and the day your module becomes outdated...either you take again a subscription...either you will have to fix the whole thing by yourself.
